# Can a bastion host be launched by auto-scaling-group for failure recovery?

Tags: amazon-elb, autoscaling, amazon-vpc

Can I launch a bastion host through auto-scaling-group, so that I set "MinSize": 1 and "DesiredCapacity": 1.

I understand that normally ASG is used along with ELB or SQS and Cloudwatch from load balancing or scaling purpose. And I feel my purpose here is different -- I want to make my bastion machine up and running, and once it's down, I want to bring it back as soon as possible. (I don't need my bastion host to be "HA", but I'd like it to be able to automatically recover, say within 3 mins)

Is there such an use case for auto scaling group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using an Auto Scaling Group in this fashion will ensure that a failed host will be replaced automatically if it fail EC2 health checks.

However, this is not the best and up to date way to solve your problem. EC2 supports [Auto Recovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-recovery-for-amazon-ec2/) as of last year. Recovery can be configured to perform a variety of actions on an instance that fails EC2 health checks. The advantage it has over Auto Scaling is that things like Elastic IPs can be migrated over to the new instance. The [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html) contain all the information you'll need to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a valid use case.
Auto scaling groups force you to setup automatically creatable instances: you define a launch configuration that specifies stuff like instance type and the image you want to launch, and the number of instances in the group.
When you set the desired instances to '1', the autoscaling group (AG) will start enforcing that one instance will be running.

Problem: the instances get assigned a different IP when they boot so you won't know where to reach it.
There are two ways around this:
- use an ELB so you can always reach it at the ELB's address. When only running one instance, this is kind of an overkill
- make the instance assign an elastic ip when it boots. I don't think that Amazon supports this out-of-the box yet, but you can find scripts that do this for you on the web.

Note that this setup won't prevent failure. But once an instance fails, it's a matter of terminating it and a new one will be backup in 5 minutes or so.

Comment: "assign an elastic ip" is exactly what I am thinking toward. Thanks, you confirmed my idea about possibility, and let me investigate further.

Comment: Part of your answer is incorrect. EC2 auto recovery can migrate Elastic IPs to new instances replacing failed ones :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link from amazon on the architecture and best practice for Bastion host - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html